# Value error when trying to insert data into Django Database Table

Tags: python, django

So I've created multiple .csv files to upload data into my tables.
Everything seems to be going well except for the part where I try to add data into a table which is has a foreign key attribute. I've seen a question that's similar but it's weird for my case since I've already added data for the primary key table.

```
<QuerySet [{'ISBN': '9780815345244', 'bookName': 'Molecular Biology of the Cell', 'bookVersion': '6', 'bookAuthor': 'Bruce Alberts', 'bookPublisher': 'W. W. Norton & Company'},
```

i get this error:

```
ValueError: Cannot assign "'9780815345244'": "retailer_book.ISBN" must be a "books" instance.
```

which is weird since it is an instance.

This is my models.py code:

```
class books (models.Model):
    ISBN = models.CharField(max_length=255, primary_key=True)
    bookName = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    bookVersion = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    bookAuthor = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    bookPublisher = models.CharField(max_length=255, default= 'NULL')

class retailer(models.Model):
    sellerID = models.CharField(max_length=255, primary_key=True)
    retailer = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class retailer_book(models.Model):
    ISBN = models.ForeignKey(books, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    sellerID = models.ForeignKey(retailer, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    condition = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    price = models.FloatField()
    reviews= models.CharField(max_length=255)
    ID =  models.CharField(max_length=255, primary_key=True)
    bookType = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

edit: my uploading script, I fixed this issue but I just wanted to know if there's a better solution to this

```
def addbooks():
    with open('./book.csv') as f:
            reader = csv.reader(f)
            for row in reader:
                _, created = books.objects.get_or_create(
                    ISBN=row[0],
                    bookName=row[1],
                    bookAuthor=row[2],
                    bookVersion=row[3],
                    bookPublisher=row[4],
                    )

def addretailerbook():
    with open('./retailerbook.csv') as f:
            reader = csv.reader(f)
            for row in reader:
                _, created = retailer_book.objects.get_or_create(
                    ID = row[0],
                    sellerID_id=row[1],
                    ISBN_id = row[2],
                    condition = row[3],
                    price = row[4],
                    reviews = row[5],
                    bookType= row[6],
                    )
```

Thank You!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the `ISBN` value you're trying to add to `retailer_book` is somehow a string instead of instance.

So I suggest you to put that value (`9780815345244`) into field named `ISBN_id` instead which should do the trick.

```py
retailer_book.objects.create(
    ISBN_id='9780815345244',
    ....
)
```

The reason is `ISBN` field is a foreign key field and you need an instance to put it in. But if you use the same field but call it `ISBN_id`, this will be a real data to store in the database which is a string.

See more about Django's suffix `_id` [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#database-representation)

Comment: How do you add an instance instead of a string in this case, I'll include my uploading script right now.

Comment: @simon So you need to get the book first before creating a retailer book.

Comment: @simon Like `books.objects.get(ISBN=row[2])`. But it will query the database every time you get the book. So I recommend you to stick with the current one since it does not need to query the database :)